# DateTimePicker control usage in specific scenario

Tags: .net, winforms, datetimepicker

This question is relating to a specific functionality that a client has requested for an application I am designing.  Basically, the client wants the DateTimePicker to prompt a question after the date was selected.

This sounds simple, however, I am having difficulties accomplishing this simple task.

1. **If I prompt OnCloseUp** - Keyboard entries will not execute this event
2. **If I prompt OnValueChanged** - Event fires every time the date is
   changed
3. **If I prompt OnLeave** - Event fires somewhat.  Does not fire when
   toolstrip is clicked for example. I would like to avoid this method, as it only fires once the user clicks away from the control.

So basically, I am trying to think of the best way to prompt a user AFTER they select a date from a dateTimePicker control.

I have no issues with building a custom control either.  I have started making one since I also needed to allow NULL values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up coding a custom control to handle this the right way.
I created a textbox with a button, and added a MonthCalendar control as well.

The textbox+button opens the MonthCalendar control.  The only way to choose the datetime now is via the MonthCalendar.  You cannot select from the Textbox.  I also created a custom event that fires when the date is selected.  It works perfectly.  Code below:

```
Public Class CustomDatePicker

  'Variables
  Friend WithEvents cal As MonthCalendar
  Private _isCalendarVisible As Boolean = False
  Private _currentSelectedDate As DateTime = Nothing

  'Events
  Public Event OnDateTimeSet(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal dateValue As DateTime)
  Public Event OnDateCleared(ByVal sender As Object)

  'Constructor
  Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
  End Sub

  'Onload
  Private Sub CustomDatePicker_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'Initially setup calendar
    cal = New MonthCalendar
    cal.Name = "Calendar"
    cal.MaxSelectionCount = 1
    cal.BringToFront()
    cal.Location = New Point(Me.Location.X + 5, Me.Location.Y + 25)
    Me.Parent.Controls.Add(cal)
    cal.Hide()
    _isCalendarVisible = False
  End Sub

  'Returns the currently selected date from the TextBox field
  Public ReadOnly Property CurrentSelectedDate()
    Get
      Return _currentSelectedDate
    End Get
  End Property

  'Display calendar
  Private Sub ShowCalendar()

    'Close any other custom date controls that are open on the parent form
    Dim cont As Control
    For Each cont In Parent.Controls
      If (cont.GetType().Name = "CustomDatePicker") Then
        CType(cont, CustomDatePicker).HideCalendar()
      End If
    Next

    'display the calendar
    If Not (_isCalendarVisible) Then
      tbxSelectedDate.BackColor = Color.Cornsilk
      cal.BringToFront()
      cal.Show()
      cal.Focus()
      _isCalendarVisible = True
      btnCalendarToggle.Checked = True
    End If

  End Sub

  'Hide the Calendar
  Private Sub HideCalendar()
    If (_isCalendarVisible) Then
      tbxSelectedDate.BackColor = Color.White
      cal.Hide()
      _isCalendarVisible = False
      btnCalendarToggle.Checked = False
      tbxSelectedDate.Focus()
    End If
  End Sub

  'Display the selected datetime into the textbox
  Private Sub SetDateTime()
    Me.tbxSelectedDate.Text = FormatDateTime(cal.SelectionRange.Start, DateFormat.LongDate)
    _currentSelectedDate = FormatDateTime(cal.SelectionRange.Start, DateFormat.LongDate)
    RaiseEvent OnDateTimeSet(Me, _currentSelectedDate)
  End Sub

  'Event when selection is made in the Calendar
  Private Sub Calendar_Selection(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DateRangeEventArgs) Handles cal.DateSelected
    SetDateTime()
    HideCalendar()
  End Sub

  'Handle the keyboard events associated with the calendar control
  Private Sub Calendar_KeyPress(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles cal.KeyPress
    If e.KeyChar = ChrW(Keys.Return) Then
      SetDateTime()
      HideCalendar()
    ElseIf e.KeyChar = ChrW(Keys.Escape) Then
      HideCalendar()
    End If
  End Sub

  'Handles keypresses on the textbox field
  Private Sub tbxSelectedDate_KeyUp(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles tbxSelectedDate.KeyUp
    If (e.KeyCode = Keys.Down) Then
      ShowCalendar()
    ElseIf (e.KeyCode = Keys.Delete) Then
      tbxSelectedDate.Text = ""
    End If
  End Sub

  'Show the calendar when button is clicked
  Private Sub btnCalendarToggle_MouseUp(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles btnCalendarToggle.MouseUp
    ToggleCalendar()
  End Sub

  'Show the calendar when button is 'clicked' via ENTER on keyboard
  Private Sub btnCalendarToggle_KeyPress(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles btnCalendarToggle.KeyPress
    If e.KeyChar = ChrW(Keys.Return) Then
      ToggleCalendar()
    End If
  End Sub

  'Toggle calender.  If on, turn off.  If off, turn on.
  Private Sub ToggleCalendar()
    If Not (_isCalendarVisible) Then
      ShowCalendar()
      btnCalendarToggle.Checked = True
    Else
      HideCalendar()
      btnCalendarToggle.Checked = False
    End If
  End Sub

  'When textbox value is changed, check to see if it was cleared.  If cleared, raiseevent.
  Private Sub tbxSelectedDate_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles tbxSelectedDate.TextChanged
    If (tbxSelectedDate.Text = "") Then
      _currentSelectedDate = Nothing
      RaiseEvent OnDateCleared(Me)
    End If
  End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use the OnValueChanged event.  After they change the value, ask the question.  If they answer wrong (Example - Q: Are you sure?  A: No.) then reset the datepicker and return focus to it.

This example is a little messy but it works.

```
Private is_reset As Boolean = False
Private Sub DateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DateTimePicker1.ValueChanged

    Dim answer As Integer
    If Not is_reset Then
        answer = MsgBox("Are you Sure?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo)
        is_reset = False
    End If

    If answer = MsgBoxResult.No Then
        is_reset = True
        DateTimePicker1.Value = Now
        DateTimePicker1.Select()
    End If
```

Comment: This is the main issue.  I don't want the prompt to appear everytime the value is changed.  For example, if selected with the keyboard, it would pop-up numerous times.

Answer (score 1):

"Select a date" means:

1. Choose a date with the mouse, or
2. Enter/change a date with the keyboard then move focus to another control.

So, how about a combination of `OnCloseUp` and `OnValidate`/`OnLeave`?

Start by watching for `OnValueChanged` events. Set a changed flag if one fires.

If they select with the mouse, you can bring up the prompt with `OnCloseUp` and reset your changed flag. Then watch for `OnValueChanged` events again.

When `OnValidate` or `OnLeave` fires, and your flag is set (presumably after changing the date with the keyboard), then bring up the prompt.